# Play SVG animation while hovering over button

Tags: html, animation, svg, hover

So I got this SVG that already has an animation included in the svg itself, now my question is how I would start the animation while hovering over the svg icon, the svg already has the id's for each part that moves.

And how would I reset it back when hovering out of the svg?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="family" image-rendering="auto" baseProfile="basic" 
version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="550" height="550"
```

Provided the svg itself:
https://codepen.io/Zeruw/pen/MpLRqR

Codepen project:
https://codepen.io/Zeruw/project/editor/DVeMEA/

In the project you can see when you hover over the button it becomes orange and the svg starts spinning but not the way I intended, I want it to freeze at first and once you hover over the button it plays the animation that's given inside the SVG.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please create an [MCVE].

Comment: I added the codepen project.

Comment: You will probably need to inline your SVG files, and use CSS transitions to do the animation. That way you can react to mouse hovers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, the SVG/SMIL animations inside the svg file can be modified so they work in the way you want them to, without resorting to CSS animations.

Unfortunately, the way these animations are written is ridiculously complicated. 20 keyframes were used in four additive animations per group. Since they all are of the type `animateTransform`, they can be written as their matrix product in a single animation per group. Doing the math for each keyframe leads to an obvious result: it is all `transform="rotate(a, cx, cy)"` with a constant center of rotation `cx, cy`. And the movement is so evenly paced that all these keyframes are completely unneccessary.

```
    <g id="fatherHead" transform="translate(96.35 53.15)">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="replace" type="translate" dur="0.833s"
                          keyTimes="0;.05;.1;.15;.2;.25;.3;.35;.4;.45;.5;.55;.6;.65;.7;.75;.8;.85;.9;.95;1"
                          values="176.15,157.45;177.453,158.333;178.648,159.103;179.935,159.911;181.104,160.629;182.261,161.481;183.449,162.199;184.632,162.963;185.711,163.599;186.819,164.308;187.877,165.004;188.916,165.684;189.935,166.338;190.916,166.98;191.921,167.646;192.837,168.282;193.689,168.829;194.633,169.49;195.482,169.967;196.37,170.569;196.37,170.569"
                          fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" type="rotate" dur="0.833s"
                          keyTimes="0;.05;.1;.15;.2;.25;.3;.35;.4;.45;.5;.55;.6;.65;.7;.75;.8;.85;.9;.95;1"
                          values="0,0,0;.78,0,0;1.558,0,0;2.52,0,0;3.291,0,0;4.056,0,0;5.007,0,0;5.765,0,0;6.52,0,0;7.27,0,0;8.019,0,0;8.762,0,0;9.315,0,0;10.051,0,0;10.782,0,0;11.511,0,0;12.048,0,0;12.766,0,0;13.297,0,0;14,0,0;14,0,0"
                          fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" type="scale" dur="0.833s" keyTimes="0;.25;.3;1"
                          values="1,1;1,1;1,.999;1,.999" fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum" type="translate" dur="0.833s"
                          keyTimes="0;.05;.1;.15;.2;.25;.3;.35;.4;.45;.5;.55;.6;.65;.7;.75;.8;.85;.9;.95;1"
                          values="-79.8,-104.3;-79.85,-104.4;-79.8,-104.4;-79.9,-104.4;-79.85,-104.35;-79.8,-104.35;-79.85,-104.4;-79.9,-104.4;-79.9,-104.3;-79.85,-104.35;-79.9,-104.3;-79.9,-104.35;-79.9,-104.3;-79.9,-104.3;-79.9,-104.4;-79.85,-104.4;-79.85,-104.35;-79.85,-104.4;-79.85,-104.35;-79.8,-104.35;-79.8,-104.35"
                          fill="freeze"/>
        <path d="..." />
    </g>
```

thus can be boiled down to

```
    <g id="fatherHead" transform="translate(96.35 53.15)">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum"
                          type="rotate" dur="0.833s"
                          from="0,36.691,193.224" to="14,36.691,193.224"
                          fill="freeze"/>
        <path d="..." />
    </g>
```

For the next step, you can take advantage of the fact that an animation can be started by events on any element. It would be possible to start the animation when the mouse hovers over the outermost element `Scene-1r1`, but that has a problem: Hovering would be interpreted as being over filled areas, everything inbetween the lines is "out". The solution is a capturing overlay rectangle with the size of the image viewBox:

```
<rect id="mask" x="0px" y="0px" width="550" height="550" opacity="0"/>
```

Insert that as the topmost element; `opacity="0"` makes it invisible but hoverable.

Now, the animation can get the attribute `begin="mask.mouseover"`:

```
    <g id="fatherHead" transform="translate(96.35 53.15)">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="sum"
                          type="rotate" dur="0.833s" begin="mask.mouseover"
                          from="0,36.691,193.224" to="14,36.691,193.224"
                          fill="freeze"/>
        <path d="..." />
    </g>
```

You could say, problem solved at this point. But what happens when you move the mouse out an in again? It is not very pretty.

If you want to have the heads move only once on hover and never again, simply add an attribute `restart="never"`.

If you want to have have a controlled transition back to the original position, this can be done by reversing the transition on `mouseout`. Adding up these transitions leads to false behaviour, but that can be rectified with a slightly different structure:

```
    <g id="fatherHead" transform="translate(96.35 53.15)">
      <g>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="replace"
                          type="rotate" dur="0.833s" begin="bg.mouseover"
                          from="0,36.691,193.224" to="14,36.691,193.224"
                          fill="freeze"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" additive="replace"
                          type="rotate" dur="0.1s" begin="bg.mouseout"
                          from="14,36.691,193.224" to="0,36.691,193.224"
                          fill="freeze"/>
        <path d="..." />
      </g>
    </g>
```

Now, the heads move back to their original position when the mouse leaves the image.

Complete codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJOjvg

Comment: Wow thanks a lot for this, I have 3 more svg animations but with this information I can do a lot with it.

I didn't know about the mouse mask part even, so that's really helpful.

Comment: So I went and changed the svg itself now to the one you provided me with, the svg works when I hover over it. But once I try to place it in a button and hover over it it's not working, am I missing something?

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/Zeruw/project/editor/DVeMEA/

Comment: Seems the <img> tag still does not expose the shadow DOM of SVG content. You can use the *object* tag instead: `<object data="web/svg/animFamily.svg" title="FamilyIcon" id="iconLogo"/>`. Note that additionally the `<svg>` element then needs an attribute `viewBox="0 0 550 550"`

Comment: Is it somehow not possible to give the object tag a href? so that I can make the whole button clickable while the svg plays its animation. I've tried a couple of things and somehow. it either won't play the animation or it just doesn't highlight with orange.

https://codepen.io/Zeruw/project/editor/DVeMEA/

I've tried to add href to the object tag but it's not picking it up.

Comment: `<object>` has no href attribute. There is a conceptual problem here: the SVG needs to be able to receive events, but if it does, the parent document must not get them to avoid "serving two masters". The best I can think of is wrapping the mask rect inside the svg with a `<a xlink:href="#" target="_parent">`

Comment: Thank you kindly, that did the trick. I couldn't even come up with such a solution so thanks, shame I can't upvote this as this is probably the most informative post about svg hovering and clicking a button.